# css :nth-child randomly skips a list item

Tags: html, css, background, css-sprites, css-selectors

I'm posting here after trying to resolve my problem on my own for a couple of days. I have an unordered list whose list items contain several things including a div I use to display an image coming from a sprite.

Here is the html :

```
<ul class="upperList clearfix">
            <li>
                <h3>Kit détecteur extérieur images</h3>
                <p></p>
                <div class="extrasLiBg"></div>
                <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
                elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
                qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>Bouton anti hold-up avec capture d'images</h3>
                <div class="extrasLiBg"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>Pendentif Verisure [me]</h3>
                <div class="extrasLiBg"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And here is the css :

```
    .extrasLiBg {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url('images/extras-sprite.jpg') no-repeat;
}

.extras .upperList li:nth-child(2) .extrasLiBg {background-position:-100px 0;}
.extras .upperlist li:nth-child(3) .extrasLiBg {background-position:-200px 0;}
```

My problem is, the div within the last list item somehow refuses to shift the background image, and thus displays the first, top left image in the sprite...
It's driving me nuts, there are other lists on the page too and their div have no problem displaying the right part of the sprite...

I'm using Chrome 10 btw, but the problem remains in Firefox, Safari and Opera (most recent releases).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you put up a demo online, somewhere like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), or your own server? It's a little hard to visualize without your sprite image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the selector for the thrird child, change `.upperlist` to `.upperList`.